# Why can I bind base class shared_ptr rvalue reference to derived class shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, rvalue-reference

so I know we cannot bind rvalue reference to an lvalue, so the following code won't compile:

```
class Base {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base = std::make_shared<Base>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base>&& ref = base;
}
```

but the next code can compile, and I can't figure out why.

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base>&& ref = derived;
}
```

With type deduction, `auto&&` and `T&&` are `forward reference`, because they can be lvaue reference, const reference or rvalue reference.
But here is no type deduction in my case(or what I think), maybe in share_ptr, but I'm referencing share_ptr itself, not its underlying object, so I'm stuck.

Comment: The conversion operator returns by value, i.e. its an rvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.  When that happens, a new, temporary object is created, which a `std::shared_ptr<Base>&&` can bind to.  Since that object is a prvalue, its lifetime gets extended to the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/T1EsGjT49 same thing happens